# boto3: config profile could not be found

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm testing my lambda function wrapped in a docker image and provided environment variable AWS_PROFILE=my-profile for the lambda function. However, I got an error : "The config profile (my-profile) could not be found" while this information is there in `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files. Below are my commands:

```
docker run -e BUCKET_NAME=my-bucket -e AWS_PROFILE=my-profile-p 9000:8080 <image>:latest lambda_func.handler
```

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '"body":{"x":5, "y":6}}'
```

The thing is that if I just run the lambda function as a separated python script then it works.

Can someone show me what went wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When AWS is showing how to use their containers, such as for [local AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-an-aws-glue-etl-pipeline-locally-without-an-aws-account/), they share the `~/.aws/` in **read-only** mode with the container using [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) option:

```
-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
```

Thus if you wish to follow AWS example, your docker command could be:

```
docker run -e BUCKET_NAME=my-bucket -e AWS_PROFILE=my-profile-p 9000:8080 -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro <image>:latest lambda_func.handler
```

The other way is to pass the AWS credentials using docker environment variables, which you already are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

Your home directory (`~`) is not copied to Docker container, so `AWS_PROFILE` will not work.

See here for an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html